# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "DeferredAttribute") to str

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

I am wondering anyone can help me in one of the thing I cannot get my around it and really bothering as I spent last two on it but couldnt make it.

Basically, I am building an App (Django Python) to restore the information regarding all the network device e.g hostname, IP Address, S/N, Rack info etc. but I also to enable few options like Add, Edit, Delete and Connect next to device entery. I was able to create all the options except Connect option where I am completely stuck, I am trying to query database to get the IP address information and then using Popen module to open a putty window with the ssh to that IP Address device related, I tried everything I could but nothing worked, thereofrore, asking your help if you have any idea about this ? or any other alternative method for a user when he click on connect the putty or similar app will open and he just put the login credentials and get into the device.

I am sharing my code here, let me know if I am doing something wrong.

on the show all device page, i have this code, show.html

```
<td><a href="/connect/{{ i.ip_address }}">Connect</a></td>
<!--<td><a href="/connect/{{ i.id }}">Connect</a></td>-->
```

I tried both ways, with id and ip address entry in the database

on view.py

```
def connect(request, ip_address):
hostlist_ip = HostList.ip_address
print(hostlist_ip)
Popen("putty.exe" + hostlist_ip)
return redirect('/show')
```

and in the url.py

```
path('connect/<str:ip_address>', views.connect),
or 
path('connect/<str:ip_address>', views.connect),
```

Since I am also printing the the output on the terminal I notice that it is not returning the actually IP address but return this;

```
<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x04B77C50>
```

and on the web I receiving this error

```
TypeError at /connect/10.10.32.10
can only concatenate str (not "DeferredAttribute") to str
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/connect/10.10.32.10
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
can only concatenate str (not "DeferredAttribute") to str
```

let me know if you can help.

Just a F.Y.I I already tested the Popen via python but since we not getting the actual IP address from the database I am seeing this and I am a complete newbie with html/css and Djano, however I have some basic knowledge of python, so please ignore my any stupid comments in the post.

### Many thanks

Comment: What is `i`? Can you show what you passed to the template, and how you process that in the template?

Comment: If HostList is a Model, then you're calling a field declaration. Either way, this is hard to judge without knowing what your variables are. The quickfix would be calling str() like: `Popen("putty.exe" + str(hostlist_ip))`.

Comment: hey @WillemVanOnsem, i is just one of the for loop to print the forms in the show.html

Comment: `{% for i in hostlist_key%}
    <tr>
        <!--{{ i.id }}</td>-->
        <td>{{ i.hostname }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.ip_add }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.model_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.sw_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.serial }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.rack }}</td>
        <td><a href="/edit/{{ i.id }}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="/delete/{{ i.id }}">Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="/connect/{{ i.ip_add }}">Connect</a></td>`

Comment: @Melvyn, I tried using str in the url.py and also change the variable to ip_add from the ip_address as it seems like it is already in python under ipaddress module and now I am getting this error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.65.32.19'` and my code in veiw looks like this `def connect(request, ip_add):
    ip = HostList.objects.filter(id=ip_add)
    i = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_add)
    print(i)
    return redirect('/show')`

Answer (score 0):

ahh I cannot believe I spend two day to troubleshoot this and just changed the name from ip_address to ip_add and it is working now :) i think as I mentioned above in the comment, it probably confusing with the built in module

here is simple solution:

views.py

```
def connect(request, ip_add):
    import os
    from subprocess import Popen
    Popen("powershell putty.exe " + ip_add)
    return redirect('/show')
```

url.py

```
path('connect/<str:ip_add>', views.connect),
```

I may have to find out a way if user is using the mac or linux, how I am going to change this powershell to something else. but anyhow it is working for windows

thanks all for the responses.